How can I request Storage and Camera permission and replace onRequestPermissionResult
I know there are already some questions about this but I'm going to ask it again because it didn't really help me.
I wnat to programm an Barcode and QRCode Scanner in Kotlin. For that, I need the permission from the user to access Camera an Storage but the programm wont let me get the permissions. Camera is no problem, but storage is.
Since the methods to request Permission to access the storage changed with the SDK-Versions, I don't know how to do it for all Android versions (>= Android 8.0).
On top of that, Android studio tells me that onRequestPermissionsResult() is deprecated and i fail to replace it with registerForActivityResult().
Here is my code:
private fun checkStoragePermission(): Boolean {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    }
    
private fun requestStoragePermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermissions, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        when(requestCode) {
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                //Check if some action from permission dialog performed or denied
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
                    //Check if Camera and Storage permission is granted, contains boolean, true or false
                    val cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    val storageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    //Check if both permissions granted or not
                    if (cameraAccepted && storageAccepted) {
                        //both permissions(Gallery/Camera) are granted, we can launch camera for intent
                        pickImageCamera()
                    } else {
                        //one or both permissions denied, can't launch camera intent
                        showToast("Permission for Camera and Storage is required")
                        //ask for camera and storage permission
                        requestCameraPermission()
                        requestStoragePermission()
                    }
                }
            }

            STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                //check if storage permission is granted or not
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
                    //Check if storage permission is granted, contains boolean result, either true or false
                    val storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    //Check if storage permission is granted or not
                    if (storageAccepted) {

                        //Storage Permission granted, launch Gallery
                        pickImageGallery()
                    } else {
                        //storage permission denied, cant launch gallery
                        showToast("Permission for Storage is needed")
                        //ask for permission to external storage
                        requestStoragePermission()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


Can anyone help me replace the onRequestPermissionsResult() and get the permission for storage?

For what do you need a storage permission? Not for a scanner.

to take the image and to pick an image from the gallery

For both you do not need any permission except for the first a CAMERA permission.

but don't i need the permission from the user to use the camera to take a picture and the permission to access their storage?

My god.. to take a picture you need CAMERA permission. To select a picture you do not need any permission.

ok, thanks, i'm new to coding so sorry for stupid questions

I don't think you need any permission other than camera permission. For that, manifest.xml will do the job.
Here is that permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Also the code to send a request to the launcher.
private val requestCameraLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
        if (it) {
            takePhotoLauncher.launch(photoUri)
        } else {
            onBackClicked()
        }
    }

I hope it works for you.

Yeah, i figured it out. You really only need the camera permission. It works now, thank you
